# Provider disabled with LocationListener on Android

Tags: android, localization

I try to use the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` to locate myself. When I run my application (on the emulator with eclipse and with my phone), I always detect the provider as disabled.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // refresh button
    this.b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    this.b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    this.lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    Location location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    this.t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    if (location != null)
        this.t1.setText(location.toString());
    else
        if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)==false)
            this.t1.setText("Provider disabled");
        else
            this.t1.setText("No location, please wait");

    int t = 5000;
    int distance = 5;
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, t, distance, myLocationListener);
}

public void onClick(View view){
    Location location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null)
        this.t1.setText(location.toString());
    else
        this.t1.setText("Refreshed but no location");

}
```

I checked, the option in Settings > Location > Use wireless networks is enabled.

**edit**: code corrected as mentioned by NickT but still receive no location when pushing the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write

```
if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
   this.t1.setText("Provider disabled"); // always get this
```

didn't you?

As it stands you display 'disabled' when it's enabled.

Comment: Stupid me. Thank you! But the other problem is that I don't get a location when pressing the button, how long does it take usually to get the first location ?

Comment: That would depend on signal strength, I guess. Perhaps if you set the text when you receive a location in onLocationChanged(), you will get an idea of how long it takes.

Comment: I don't know, even with a simple code like that : http://paste.pocoo.org/show/497826/ I've got nothing... Possible a configuration problem with eclipse ?